# importing postcode in Ax2012 for uk

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I am stuck at importing the postcodes there is no option for the UK In drop down list in Organisation Setup --Adress--Adress setup -- Import Postcodes. I am using Ax2012 R3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at AX 2012 FP, that's probably because there is no option to import UK zipcodes. The enum only contains the one you see in the drop down list (BE, NL, SE and US). These then correspond to the a class that extends AddressZipCodeImport that do the actual importing.

If you want an option in that screen to import UK zipcodes, you'll have to program it yourself. This should be very straightforward. The easiest way is probably to import a CSV file with your data into the LogisticsAddressZipCode table.